# Facebook api token changed

Tags: facebook-graph-api, access-token

I have a facebook app that was reading my friend's wall, I used to get access_token via

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?type=client_cred&client_id={0}&client_secret={1}&grant_type=client_credentials
```

And there was no problem, now I made some changes in the app config in facebook (among them now it's a desktop app instead of web/canvas app) and this method of getting a token stopped working, now I need to get token with another method where user (me) has to login and grant permissions to application, then this token is valid for all reads I do next.

The thing is I don't know why this changed occured, I see is somethign related with `offline_access` but I can´t find how to get `access_token` for `offline_access` with this same api method:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?type=client_cred&client_id={0}&client_secret={1}&grant_type=client_credentials
```

So question is: Can you ask for offline_access token with this method: oauth/access_token?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no seperate procedure to obtain a offline access token. Just include the offline_access keyword in your list of permissions and the token obtained thereafter, by your usual method will not expire.

Comment: How can I include the list of permissiones in oauth/access_token querystring?

Comment: Here is a link to the C# code for adding the permission tokens and requesting the access token from facebook. It uses the facebook SDK from codeplex. http://facebooksdk.blogspot.com/2011/03/facebookloginhelper.html